# Is there a quicker alternative to using performance counters to find CPU usage and memory usage of a process?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I have found tonnes of similar questions all over the internet as to why performance counters are so slow to initialize, especially for a remote machine. For some people, including me, it takes more than 2 minutes to simply initialize one to get the cpu usage of a process. No one has yet suggested a proper solution to make it faster which leads me to think that there 'is' no solution if I stick to using performance counters. So I was wondering, is there an alternative way I can find the CPU Usage and Memory Usage for processes running on a remote computer that is comparatively quicker?

Comment: 2 minutes sounds pretty outrageous. Have you tried rebuilding the performance counter hives on those machines? (`C:\Windows\System32>lodctr /R`)

Comment: In my case, it might be due to a network problem as well. I've tried it on other machines, and it has significantly dropped down, to around 20 seconds on some. But it is still quiet a lot of time, especially because I need to have performance counters for multiple processes. It works much quickly on my local machine. As for the machine I'm trying to access, I do have administrative privileges. However, I'm trying to get rid of performance counters totally, whether it be a 15 second or a 10 second delay for a single process. It all adds up to a huge amount of loading time for multiple services.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would be a good share of knowledge for all those stuck with the same problem, especially when there are no other external sources with a solution, which I do think is within the scopes of Stack Overflow.